# Context based teaching pedagogy in physics

Tags: resource-recommendations, soft-question, education

*Apologies if this is not the place for such type of questions, please suggest the related community.*

Q1) Why most of the college physics textbooks are descriptive in nature, like they give the definitions of the terms and concepts and only describe processes. Instead they could give historical perspectives, reason for why the concept was developed,how a particular equation invented/discovered and in what context, interrelation with literature, culture,technology and other STEM subjects, etc.

Q2) If anyone know books (which use such pedagogy) on Mechanics, Electricity and Magnetism, Thermodynamics, Quantum mechanics etc, please do tell.

Comment: History of Science is different subject with different goals than Science itself.

Comment: I think this is a nice question. However, it could be opinion based. I fully agree with your points raised in Q1). I guess most introductory text books simply can't spend too many pages with talking about e.g. the (interesting and important) historical context etc. Usually, they cannot even cover all 'relevant' topics (i.e. all equations and physical concepts etc.) in full detail. Nevertheless, I think most books still cover at least a bit of the things you describe. Further, there are many books on e.g. the philosophy or history of physics.

Comment: @Hilmar I don't know about other students but I personally struggle understanding new concepts without the above mentioned contexts. Yes history of science is another subject but I guess it's like assuming everyone is robot and just need to know the equations and definitions without telling how concepts evolved and interrelating with other subjects.

Comment: One interesting book for Mathematical Physics is Simmons' [Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=VqWKDQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false). I like it, but not everyone does.

Answer (score 3):

You raise an interesting point.  Early on in the study of physics (or any science) students get the impression that the progress of science is very linear and always forward moving, without a full understanding of the missteps and struggles that scientists experienced in their search for scientific principles.  I think the reason for this is content driven.  There is so much information and content to cover that the history, context, interconnection with other fields and the very human aspect of science is often overlooked, or only briefly discussed.

Unfortunately, I am not aware of any good books that address your concern for the content area you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Teaching a historical perspective on any topic in science takes much more time than simply teaching the final state of the topic. The history of any topic will include dead ends, misunderstandings, diversions, disputes over priority etc. - science almost never proceeds in a straight line. Also, understanding the historical perspective requires a general knowledge of the historical background of the relevant period (e.g. to understand why Copernicus was so reluctant to publish his heliocentric theory requires a knowledge of the religious tensions in Northern Europe at that time). A college course or textbook simply doesn’t have time or space to cover all that additional material.

Having said that, there are books which take a historical approach - they are just not standard college textbooks. One example is Arthur Koestler’s *The Sleepwalkers*, which gives an historical account of the development of astronomy.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the professor gives context (mostly historical), either in the lectures or the lecture notes (or both).  The context of a theory is not the same as the theory it self and it shouldn't be treated as such.  Personally, I skim or even skip the parts where there is a "historical introduction" in a book or lecture notes.  If I wanted such perspective, I would read a popular science book (and there are plenty of pop science books that talk about the subjects you mentioned).

Some context is important, and I'm happy with the context I get from the lectures, or even the preface of my textbook.  But I definitely wouldn't want context to be mixed with the theory when trying to understand complex subjects.

Unfortunately, I do not know textbooks which use such a pedagogy.

Comment: Unfortunately in this pandemic times lectures from professors are not possible. Alos, I live in a developing country, education system is not so great.

Comment: This is understandable, I wish the best to you!  I wouldn't worry to much about what you mentioned when studying physics, you don't need much context to understand a given subject.  The youtube channel "PBS spacetime" sometimes gives a historical context (for example check their video on the ultraviolet catastrophe).  You can also find lectures on youtube, so that could be a good start: you won't get lost when studying on your own.  Whenever you need help with understanding something, just google it, and if you can't find an answer ask here in the site!

Comment: Thanks for support.